# Powershell output redirection Encoding Issue

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, ascii

I have a PS script to copy relative paths of all the files in a folder to a text file.

```
(gci -path Passion_Flower_positive_images -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","" > Passion_Flower_positive_images_txt.txt
```

After running this, I checked the output, it seemed normal. So, I went ahead with the procedure which took this file as input. As soon I ran the procedure in cmd, it displayed it some "weird" characters resulting in total disruption and undefined behavior.

It took me a long time to figure it out. I ran manually the same procedure using unix import **find.exe** and replacing all the path-delimiter characters from '\' to '/' and EOL to CR-LF -exhausting a little but it had worked in the past.

Now, I took the output of gci command(which wasn't working) and did the **"Advanced save options"** in VS2013 to change the encoding(which I found to be Unicode) from Unicode to European windows-1252. Now, I fed the same file to procedure and it worked!!

I searched for various solutions to default the encoding to Ascii. I read one solution and did this:

```
(gci -path Passion_Flower_positive_images -recurse *.jpg|Resolve-path -relative) -replace "\\","/" -replace "[.]/","" | out-file -path Passion_Flower_positive_images_txt.txt -encoding ascii
```

But it ended up in some error which I couldn't see as it exited.

Then I typed the following:

```
PS C:\> $OutputEncoding
```

I received:
PS F:_102flowers-500X500> $OutputEncoding

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : IBM437
EncodingName      : OEM United States
HeaderName        : IBM437
WebName           : IBM437
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 437
```

This however makes me wonder if default encoding specified here is `WindowsCodePage   : 1252` indeed, why did the manual change work and Is there really a need for changing the encoding? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of using `Out-File` you could also use `Set-Content` which defaults to ascii.

Comment: @Matt : Lemme try that.

Comment: This also depends on the output program expecting ascii encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The `$OutputEncoding` variable is by default set to ASCII. To get your desired result you might change the encoding to `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding`.